# Recommendation for a Dynamic Table Plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation, pages

Can anyone recommend plugin that I can use to add a table to a page? I've seen ones that use static data-- you hardcode the figures in the table. I want to pull the data from a custom db table and put it in a table.

I looked at [WP Table Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/), but I'm not sure whether, it's possible to use it with dynamic data.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a custom page template and in the content of the template use [WPDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query your table.

Example to get a row:

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->links WHERE link_id = 10");
```

Comment: Hi GavinR, Thank you for your message. Would this work: $mylink = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_my_custom_table WHERE link_id = 10"); Where wp_my_custom_table is a table I create in the wp database? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you are looking for would be ProjectManager http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/projectmanager/ without creating the database tables manually.

Comment: Hi Bainternet, Thank you for the suggestion. In my situation, I think that I'll need a custom table.